# Why Eclipse Java Editor doesn't work?

Tags: java, eclipse

In my Eclipse, all the java files will be rightly showed in package explore,but when i try to open a java file in Java Editor, I will see nothing but this.[image]

And it is so strange that i can do format code or show outline . I try to open this file with Text editor, and it works well.
I try to find something useful in eclipse log file.After eclipse start up, the log file contains no errors and exceptions.After I open two java file and click the outlines, eclipse will collect an exception.There are two snippets in log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2016-08-20 19:03:42.792
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextRenderer.calculateClientArea(StyledTextRenderer.java:230)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.resetCache(StyledText.java:7955)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.redraw(StyledText.java:7516)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.CursorLinePainter.drawHighlightLine(CursorLinePainter.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.CursorLinePainter.paint(CursorLinePainter.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.PaintManager.paint(PaintManager.java:299)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.PaintManager.selectionChanged(PaintManager.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:163)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireSelectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2734)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.selectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2713)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setSelectedRange(TextViewer.java:2398)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setSelection(JavaEditor.java:2367)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSelectionChanged(JavaEditor.java:2435)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaOutlinePage$3.open(JavaOutlinePage.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

 !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-08-20 19:03:43.007
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index out of bounds)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index out of bounds
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4472)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.getOffsetAtLine(StyledText.java:4403)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.JFaceTextUtil.getPartialTopIndex(JFaceTextUtil.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.JFaceTextUtil.getPartialTopIndex(JFaceTextUtil.java:151)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn.getInclusiveTopIndexStartOffset(AnnotationRulerColumn.java:556)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn.doPaint1(AnnotationRulerColumn.java:707)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn.doubleBufferPaint(AnnotationRulerColumn.java:532)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn.redraw(AnnotationRulerColumn.java:815)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn$6.run(AnnotationRulerColumn.java:798)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
... 23 more
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Eclipse. There can be multiple reasons. Typical workaround are 1st making sure you're using a recent version or looking in the <workspace>/.metadata/.log for additional hints (that you should usually attach to your question by the way). If this persist, you can report this issue to http://bugs.eclipse.org .

Comment: thx u you so much. 7 days ago it still work well. The log contains no errors or exceptions after start. But when i click the outline , it will report an exception . I will add it on my question

Comment: Seems to be bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471192, which was fixed a while ago. Try a fresh Neon install.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Does Neob work? If so I'll make my comment an answer so it'd be more visible.

Comment: I am not very sure.I change eclipse to Neon and my system get an update(win 10 ),then it was solved